# Shared service for multiple web service sessions

Tags: java, web-services, webserver, server, server-side

I have a requirement to design shared service

Example scenario:

```
User 1 logs into web service localhost:8080/checkin?latitude=98.6&longitude=95.2
User 2 logs into web service localhost:8080/checkin?latitude=78.9&longitude=84.9
User 3 logs into web service localhost:8080/checkin?latitude=85.3&longitude=73.5
```

I need to design a service which can take latitude and longitude from all the users and return nearest user pairs.

How can I write this kind of shared service?
or Is there any server application that can fit into this scenario?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by 'User X logs into web service', just that they hit that url?

Comment: User X is using an Android app and makes REST call to server, sending his current location(lat, long)

Comment: Writing latitude and longitude in database is out of consideration because I need real time results

Comment: yes. along with some additional data user will hit the url and service should return information of nearest user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a singleton pattern, any of those options are valid.

- Storing values on a static Map
- If you use Spring or jsf you can use a application scoped bean

Comment: If you use a map there is a very good chance you will run out of memory. If the information is to be stored in an in memory data structure there needs to be a strategy for limiting the size of that data structure

Comment: Any other solution apart from using Spring?

Comment: I am not saying using spring is a bad idea, I'm saying using a map is a bad idea. Have a look at guava's caches; some details - https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained